# Gpu passthrough, Intel_IOMMU not on but cpu supports vt-d

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, virtualization, gpu

Specs:

Laptop: HP Pavilion G6 2205-ep

OS: Kali Linux (Debian based)

CPU: Intel i5-3210M (VT-d enabled)

GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000

GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7670m

Hello, I'm currently facing a problem where I enable intel_iommu=on in the grub config, run "update-grub", reboot, but when I go and check if it is enabled with "dmesg | grep -e IOMMU" it says:

> [0.000000] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
>
> [1.181069] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel
>
> [1.181070] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system

It says that the AMD IOMMU is not available though I'm using an intel cpu and not an AMD one so that was to be expected.

My goal is to be able to passthrough the gpu to qemu-kvm, I'm able to start vfio-pci and unbind the gpu from the kernel, but I'm not able to bind it to the vfio driver, the only thing that comes to my mind is that it is because the Intel_IOMMU is not properly enabled.